# Image uploaded through Carrierwave not found when Rails server is started with relative url root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

We are using CarrierWave to upload images and they get stored under /public/uploads/#{model.id}

When we start the server as **rails s**, url gets generated as

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/1
```

But when start the server as **RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/myapp' rails s**, url gets generated as

```
http://localhost:3000/myapp/uploads/1
```

I get 404 response as the files are still under /public folder.

How to fix this path issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following line in config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
config.base_path = ''
```